# UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I am currently trying my hands on Amazon cognito. I am trying to access a record in dataset held by the identity_id of the pool I created. Below is the code on how I initialize amazon cognito:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var cognitoConfig = {
    "accessKeyId": "gibberish"//AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    "secretAccessKey": "secret_gibberish" //AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    "sessionToken": null,
    "region": "us-east-1",
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({        
        IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:cb879fe2-b638-44dd-826d-fabc10ac639f'
    }), 
};
AWS.config.update(cognitoConfig);
```

I am using cognito sync for accessing the record in dataset under the specified identitiy_id.

```
var cognitosync = new AWS.CognitoSync();
cognitosync.listRecords({
            DatasetName: config.COGNITO_USERS_DATASET,
            IdentityId: identity_id,
            IdentityPoolId: config.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
        }, function (err, data) {

            if (err) {
               console.log("Cognito Error: ", err);
            }

            var identity_records = {};

            data.Records.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item) {
                    identity_records[item.Key] = item.Value;
                }
            });              

        });
```

When I execute these lines of code, I get the following

```
error: { [UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.]
  message: 'The security token included in the request is invalid.',
  code: 'UnrecognizedClientException',
  time: Wed Nov 09 2016 17:07:10 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  requestId: '1b2550a8-a69f-11e6-8c97-37b2029bd20b',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 93.38622682262212 }
```

What is wrong I am doing? Please enlighten me on what I am missing.

Comment: Where are you pulling the value for 'identity_id' from?

Comment: @mat Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm getting the same error.